# "egrep: empty (sub)expression" when attempting to filter out words from a list

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to follow this question/answer from Server Fault: [In tail -f, how do I filter out stuff that has certain keywords?](https://serverfault.com/q/270756/145545)

The following is producing ***`egrep: empty (sub)expression`***:

```
# Respect user's preferred flags, but filter the stuff we explicitly test
#  Retain allowed flags in ADD_CXXFLAGS
if [ ! -z "CXXFLAGS" ]; then
    ADD_CXXFLAGS=$(echo "$CXXFLAGS" | egrep -v '(\-DDEBUG|\-DNDEBUG|\-O[0-9]|\-Os|\-Og|)')
else
    ADD_CXXFLAGS=
fi

echo "User CXXFLAGS: $CXXFLAGS"
echo "Retained CXXFLAGS: $ADD_CXXFLAGS"
```

Google was not very helpful in providing me suggestions: ["egrep: empty (sub)expression"](http://www.google.com/search?q="egrep%3A+empty+(sub)expression"). Half of them looked Chinese (literally).

I've tried the simple stuff I know, like replacing single quote with double quote, escaping and not escaping the dash, and similar beginner stuff.

I'm on OS X, which is usually a flavor of the BDSs. But this might be some non-standard Apple behavior.

What's wrong with the expression or sub-expression?

---

Later, the script uses it like follows. For example, we want to remove `-DDEBUG` and `-DNDEBUG`, but retain `-maes`, `-mrdrnd` and `-mrdseed`. Hence the reason we want to filter out some flags, but not other.

```
# Test Debug build, -O2
export CXXFLAGS="-DDEBUG -g2 -O2 $ADD_CXXFLAGS"
make...

# Test Release build, -O2
export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 $ADD_CXXFLAGS"
make...

# Test Debug build, -O3
export CXXFLAGS="-DDEBUG -g2 -O3 $ADD_CXXFLAGS"
make...

# Test Release build, -O3
export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 $ADD_CXXFLAGS"
make...

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. This should be the last question, and I can go through and accept best answers once everything works (for this and the other question).

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
egrep -v '(\-DDEBUG|\-DNDEBUG|\-O[0-9]|\-Os|\-Og|)'
```

With:

```
egrep -v '(\-DDEBUG|\-DNDEBUG|\-O[0-9]|\-Os|\-Og)'
```

This removes the empty subexpression at the end of the `egrep` regex.

#### Discussion

Compare the following two regexes, the first without an empty subexpression and the second with one:

```
$ echo abc | egrep -v '(none|such)'
abc
$ echo abc | egrep -v '(none|such|)'
$
```

`(none|such)` matches either `none` or `such`.  By contrast, `(none|such|)` matches either `none` or `such` or nothing at all.  Since all input matches the last, the `egrep -v` command removes everything from the input.

Comment: Thank you very much. Interestingly, Linux took it without complaint.  I can't apologize enough for these beginner questions....

Answer (score 2):

Your error is the empty `|)`. 
However, if you want to **remove certain words from a single line**, egrep is not going to help you. You need to use something like `sed`:

```
export ADD_CXXFLAGS=$(echo " $CXXFLAGS " | sed 's/ /  /g;s/ \(-DDEBUG\|-DNDEBUG\|-O[0-9]\|-Os\|-Og\) / /g')
```

The above adds a space around the flags to simplify, then replaces any of your
words by a space.  Hence `CXXFLAGS="-DDEBUG -g2 -O2 $ADD_CXXFLAGS"` becomes `ADD_CXXFLAGS=-g2`.

---

Note you can do this sort of manipulation inside your Makefile instead:

```
ADD_CXXFLAGS=$(filter-out -DDEBUG -DNDEBUG -O1 -O2 -O3 -04 -O5 -O6 -O7 -O8 -O9 -Os -Og, $(CXXFLAGS))
```

Comment: *"Note you can do this sort of manipulation inside your Makefile instead..."* - exactly. I was looking for the shell's equivalent of `filter-out`, but I could not find it. And its the reason why I used "filter out" in the title of the question. Others searching for it should find it this question.

Comment: *"if you want to remove certain words from a single line, egrep is not going to help you..."* - I was suspicious of that, and I even reproduced the result you predicted. I *thought* it was something I was doing wrong or some behavior Apple changed. I was going to ask some other maintainers to test and comment...

Comment: I had to edit the sed and add to the start `s/ /  /g;` to duplicate spaces. This is because my simple replacement of <space>keyword<space> by <space> does not allow two adjacent keywords to be removed, as the single intervening space is gobbled up, and sed does not try to use the replacement space.  (We cannot use `\b` which means "word boundary", because `-` is not in the definition of a word.)